Which preposition should I use with 'similar age' and why?
Examples:

I spoke with a boy of a similar age
I spoke with a boy in a similar
age
I spoke with a boy at a similar age


'Of' is the answer.

Without further context, we wouldn't know if the meaning was "close to my own age" or "close in age to the age of some other person".  For example, the police could be interrogating witnesses who saw a crime, and a few of them could be minors. One detective could say "I spoke to a girl who was about ten years old" and another detective could say "I spoke to a boy of a similar age".  If you want to refer to your own age, it would be more idiomatic to say "about my own age".

When discussing the preposition to use with the phrase "similar age," the most appropriate choice is "of". Let's break down the usage of each preposition — "with," "in," and "at" — in great detail, with examples and evidence, to fully understand why "of" is the most suitable.
1. "Of a similar age"
The preposition "of" is used when we refer to the relationship between a noun (such as a person, object, or group) and a particular characteristic or property. In this case, "age" is the characteristic being attributed to "the boy."
Why "of" is correct:

Genitive relationship: In English, when we describe something that belongs or relates to something else, we use "of." This includes cases where we're expressing that someone or something has a specific attribute or quality, such as a "similar age."
Standard usage with "similar": The word "similar" often collocates with the preposition "of" in a descriptive sense. When you want to describe someone having the same or a comparable attribute, you typically use "of." For instance:

"He is a man of great wealth."
"She is a woman of extraordinary talent."
"I spoke with a boy of a similar age."



In all these cases, the phrase is essentially saying that the person has a certain characteristic, in this case, "age," which is similar to someone or something else. Thus, "of" correctly conveys this idea.
Example:

"I spoke with a boy of a similar age."
This means the boy belongs to the group of individuals who share a similar age to that of the speaker or other person(s).

2. "In a similar age"
The preposition "in" generally indicates location or position inside something, or a state or condition that someone or something is within. For example:

"He is in a hurry."
"I found it in the drawer."

However, "in" is not appropriate when we are describing someone's age or a characteristic they possess. The phrase "in a similar age" would suggest that the boy is physically located or situated within a similar age, which is not logical in this context. Age isn’t a physical space but rather an attribute or range of years, so "in" does not fit when talking about attributes like age.
Why it's incorrect:

Age is an attribute, not a location.
Using "in" would imply being inside or within something, which doesn't apply to age as a concept.

Thus, "in" is not correct here because it doesn’t convey the intended relationship between the boy and the similarity in age.
Example (incorrect):

"I spoke with a boy in a similar age."
This would sound unnatural and confusing because "in" doesn’t logically describe how a person shares a similarity in age.

3. "At a similar age"
The preposition "at" is often used to describe a specific point in time, a location, or an event. For instance:

"She is at the bus stop."
"He is at a crossroads in his life."
"She arrived at 6 PM."

However, "at" is typically used to indicate a specific moment or a precise location. When we use "at" with age, it implies a particular point in age, such as "at the age of 15" or "at age 30." This usage denotes a very specific age or stage, which is different from saying someone shares a similar age. The phrase "at a similar age" would indicate a fixed point in age, not a comparison between two people’s ages.
Why "at" is incorrect:

Age is generally not presented as a precise point in this case.
"At" doesn’t fit the comparative or generalized context needed to talk about similar ages.

Example (incorrect):

"I spoke with a boy at a similar age."
This suggests that the boy is at a specific moment or stage of life, which is not the intended meaning. The speaker isn’t talking about a fixed moment or age but about a range or general similarity.

4. Further Evidence and Explanation

Collocations with "similar": In English, "similar" is most commonly followed by the preposition "of" when we are discussing an attribute or characteristic shared by multiple subjects. For instance, "a man of similar height," "a group of similar interests," or "a region of similar climate." This pattern follows a standard structure for describing things that share a common characteristic, which supports the usage of "of" in this case.

"Similar age" as an attribute: Age is considered a descriptive attribute rather than a specific point in time. So, when comparing or relating one person’s age to another, we refer to it in terms of possession (i.e., "a similar age"), not location or a point in time.


